# "If exist" pattern to match files, but not directories

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, file-exists

I have a Windows batch script which uses `if exist`, *(I replaced long pathnames with `SomePath`)*:

```batch-file
if exist "D:\SomePath\Blah\Inbox\*.*" CALL :SUB_MoveFiles Blah
```

The `Inbox` directory, in this example, has two subdirectories, `Archive` and `Work`.

If the `Inbox` directory contains files, the `if exist` succeeds, and the subroutine is `call`ed, *(where all the files in the `Inbox` are processed)*.

If the `Inbox` directory contains only subdirectories, the `if exist` also succeeds, (ERRORLEVEL is `0`), and the subroutine is `call`ed. However it fails miserably because there are no files to process.

I've looked at, (but not yet tried), the `for /f` command, but havent thought of a way to make it work.

The `SUB_Movefiles` subroutine is designed to work on all the files in the `Inbox` at once, (that is, it does not traverse subdirectories).

I am looking for a way to have the `If Exist` command only succeed if there are files in the `Inbox`. Alternatively, a way to make the pattern `*.*` work as I expect, (i.e. `*.*` should not match the subdirectories, only files with names including a period).

Here is the subroutine, (most of it anyway).

```batch-file
:SUB_MoveFiles
REM Archive inbound files
REM Combine multiple files into one file
REM Copy to EDI Inbound
REM Archive combined file

echo ERRORLEVEL is %ERRORLEVEL%
echo ===== Processing Trading Partner %1 ===== >> %LogFile%
MOVE "D:\SomePath\%1\Inbox\*.*" "D:\SomePath\%1\Inbox\work\" 
copy "D:\SomePath\%1\Inbox\work\*.*" "D:\SomePath\%1\Inbox\work\%1_Inbound_%d%_%t%.edi"  
rem Finish Archiving
echo ===== Archiving Trading Partner %1 ===== >> %LogFile%
copy "D:\SomePath\%1\Inbox\work\%1_Inbound*.edi" "D:\SomePath\EDI\edidata\inbound\"
echo copy "D:\SomePath\%1\Inbox\work\%1_Inbound*.edi" "\\Server\C$\CommonReceive"
move "D:\SomePath\%1\Inbox\work\*.*" "D:\SomePath\%1\Inbox\archive\"
echo.

exit /B
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the scripting language you're using. Also, why not post the content of `SUB_MoveFiles`?

Comment: Also, be unambiguous about where the "files" (your double-quotes, not mine) exist in the path that you want to process. Are they in the `Inbox` folder? Or are they in the subfolders? Or both?

Comment: This is a MS Batch script...
The SUB_Movefiles "function" is just a collection of Move and Copy lines that Archive the files and Move them to a Communication Server... Currently it is designed to process all the files in the Inbox

I want to process all the files in the Inbox and not traverse the Subfolders

Comment: FWIW "Blah" happens to be a "Partner". Processing the Inbox is processing the Inbound documents for that Partner that day (session). I didn't come up with this Design (processing the entire folder instead of file by file), but I did create that SUB_Movefiles routine... That collapsed the scripts into a few hundred lines.... For some of the Partners, we have a specific pattern (e.g. *.DAT, or *-*...). For some other partners there is no predictable pattern (that has at least been related to me).....  So getting the "*.*" (asterisk-dot-asterisk) pattern to work as "Predicted" is paramount....

Comment: FWIW I reviewed MS pages and the "dot" (Or "period") is not considered a wildcard character.... Although the pattern `*.*` is used in a lot of examples of a pattern to match "Everything".... Seems a bit ambiguous to me...

Comment: `*.* ` comes from DOS (command.exe), where it matches "anyName-dot-anyextenison" i-e. did not list files starting with a dot or without an extension. This behaviour changed with the Windows Command Line (cmd.exe), where `*` matches "all files" and `*.*` is treated as "any name (even empty)"-dot-"anyExtension (even empty)" - in short: in `cmd.exe`, `*` and `*.*` is the same. For the "lot of examples": habits die hard.

Comment: I would advise that you just use the `Dir` command, with conditional execution. Example: ```Dir "D:\SomePath\Blah\Inbox" /A:-D 1>NUL 2>&1 && Call :SUB_MoveFiles "Blah"```. Please note that the argument is quoted, _(best practice)_, which consequently means all instances of `%1`, in your subroutine, should be replaced with `%~1`. This should only run the `Call` command `if` at least one file `exist`s in `Inbox`.

Comment: Thanx, that looks promising, cant try it soon, but I will...